# Error when trying to open gedit

Tags: gedit

I got a error when opening gedit. It is weird. I don't know how to fix it.
I tried:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall gedit
```

But, still getting the same error:
[image]

Is there are any kind of repair? I don't know if it was because I was following a tutorial with R.
However, I did not run any kind of config script.

After click ok it works (after a delay from 1 second +-).

Thank you all.

Comment: what happens after clicking "OK"?

Comment: @pLumo After click ok it works (after a delay from ~1 second ).

Comment: Is Gedit set to open the last file you edited when it starts? If it is (check preferences) but you removed that file, that would explain your error. If you just open another file dose it go away?

Comment: @MarkKirby You got it.

Comment: I would call this a bug in `gedit`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark kirby suggestion:

" Is Gedit set to open the last file you edited when it starts? If it is (check preferences) but you removed that file, that would explain your error."

**Solution**:

*I just had my text editor gedit customized to open the last document and due my mistake, it was a deleted one.
I just open another text document and the error was fixed!!*
As simple as that!

Thank you!

Comment: Please, be more productive. Explain step by step the actions you took.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved using *dconf-editor* by browsing to

`/org/gnome/gedit/plugins/filebrowser/virtual-root`